# Problem with HTTP server, port forwarding and WNR614 router

Tags: networking

I have a big problem. I want to make rpi web server. I bought myself a router few days ago. The newest version of netgear wnr614. Everything was fine to the moment i tried to forward the port. It seems like the router has some firewall, that is impossible to turn off or add exclusion. I don't know what to do. I even made myself dynamic dns and still it doen't works...
Please help, Maciej

Answer (score 0):

you will need to clarify a bit your question: what is exactly the problem you are seeing?

I will try anyway to provide some clues.

### Background Info

Most (if not all) consumers router use what is sometimes advertised as a firewall (but which isn't) [NAT or Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). It means that your router has one public IP address while your other devices on your LAN share a subnet which is not routable and is part of a private IP range (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24). Because those [private addresses are not routable by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), they are not accessible from the internet. So this create a barrier between the outside world and your local network. So it accomplishes the same as a firewall which would block all incoming traffic but allow all outgoing traffic.

NAT is not something you can disable, unless your ISP can provide a public IP address for each of your device on your local network. It would mean also that you would really need to build a firewall to protect each of your devices because by using public IPs, they would be all accessible directly from the internet.

However, when you need to allow one of your local computer (with a private IP address) to be accessible to the internet, what you do is actually open the port on the router public IP address and ask the router to forward any incoming connection to this part to a particular computer in your local network. This is called "Port Forwarding" on most Netgear router administration pages.

### Setting Up your router to make your RPi a public web server

If you want to set-up port forwarding to your Raspberry Pi (RPi). First login to your router, and **set a fix IP address for your RPi**, this is done in "Advanced > Setup > LAN IP", see your [router's manual at chapter Reserve LAN IP Addresses](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/JNR1010V2/Generic_N150_N300_Wireless_Router_UM_16Oct2014.pdf#G6.112086)). Choose a fix IP addess for your RPi and remember it.

Then go **configuring "Port Forwarding"** (the manual does not have a dedicated section on that, so it is possible that it does not support it, however there is one [knowledge base article for your device](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/24047/~/how-do-i-configure-port-forwarding-on-my-rp614,-mr814,-wgr101,-wgr614,-wgt624,)), look at the intructions on that page and add a new HTTP service on port 80 or HTTPS on port 443 and specify the IP address you chose for your RPi.

On your RPi, it might be necessary to reboot it (or disconnect and reconnect the network) if you choose a different fixed IP address than the one currently assigned. Then you will need to install your web server (e.g. Apache `sudo apt-get install apache2` or Nginx `sudo apt-get install nginx`) and make sure that if you use a firewall on the RPi that it allows incoming connections on port 80 or port 443. To know if you have an active firewall: `sudo iptables -L -n`.

Comment: I have got apache2 and mysql db. Problem that I see is that i cant connect to forwarded port. I have read in internet that my problem could be solved getting roi static IP and dynamic dns to router. But it doesnt works

Comment: I think your router does not do NAT loopback. So it means you can't from your local LAN use your public IP (or domain if you have one such as dyndns and co) to connect to your RPi web server. I had a WGR614 (so an older version of yours) and it did not support NAT loopback. There is no easy solutions: a) you could buy a new router which has this feature; b) you could try to set up apache that it responds for the same resources to 2 different domains (the public one and an internal one).  The first solution costs money. The second might not work with all PHP blog/CMS.

Comment: @MaciejM do you have more questions? Was my answer helpful or did it actually answered your question (even though you might have found you have yet another problem)? If yes, then either update your question or add a comment, or +1 the answer if it was helpful or accept it as an answer.